# VSTS minimize get source task

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a VSTS build setup. Currently we have a single repository hosting multiple services. We have a build definition per service, and triggers each only when the current service is touched, by a trigger pattern. 
Now the issue is that each build definition hence the single repository makes the GetSource download the whole repo and also we do a clean. 
I have been searching to see if there is a solution like the trigger where we can set a pattern, to just get a part of the repository downloadet. This should be to reduce build/download time.

A workaround might be to not make a clean each time or make multiple repositories. At the moment we would like to avoid the latter.

Let me hear if anyone knows of a good solution.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: The better way is separate the projects, packaging the common project as nuget package and upload to feed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify the files to be downloaded in Get Sources step. Instead, VSTS will download the whole repo.

The workaround is set **Clean** option as **false** so that only the modified files and new added files will be updated in Get Sources step.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was also one of our option, only thing is that "it's always good to build on a clean machine". Rethinking the issue, it might also be a good idea to spil our repo into more, as it contains independent services, just a bit more of work.

Comment: If your repo contains unrelated works, you do should split them into separate repos. And it can also help you to track versions for different works more clearly.

Comment: No doubt about that. As always we just need to find the right time to do it.